# Assign Background Color to ListView based on TextWriter input wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a `ListView` on which I redirect the output to as follows using a implementation of `TextWriter`:

```
ScriptEngine pyEngine;
pyEngine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();
Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Synchronized(new ListViewWriter(lbIpyOutput, Dispatcher)));
```

I want to achieve a achieve a colored background of a `ListView item` based on an Enum value.

In most example here on SO a `DataBinding` is used for that which is a property of a class. For me the color is not dependent on any property but rather an `Enum`. Atm I make use of a method to format the output.

```
public static void WriteToConsole(string _stringToWrite)  
{
    string output = String.Format("PY | {0} | {1} | {2}", tagCount, DateTime.Now, _stringToWrite);   
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    tagCount++;
}
```

`ListViewWriter` is an implementation of `TextWriter`

```
class ListViewWriter : TextWriter
    {
        private ListView listView;

        public ListViewWriter(ListView _listBox, Dispatcher _dispatcher)
        {
            listView = _listBox;
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string value)
        {
            base.WriteLine(value);
            listView.Items.Add(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Since `DataBinding` doesn't seem like an option I was imagining to do a override `Console.WriteLine(String _stringToWrite, MyEnum enum)` but that obviously doesn't work because `TextWriter` finds "no suitable method to override".

I created a converter class as well but didn't know how to put to any good use (not sure if it's actually possible to use hex values as string):

```
class OutputBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Severity severity = (Severity)value;
            string bgColor = "Gray";

            switch (severity)
            {
                case Severity.CRITIC:
                    bgColor = "27ae60"; //carrot orange
                    break;
                case Severity.DEBUG:
                    bgColor = "3498db"; //peter river blue
                    break;
                case Severity.ERROR:
                    bgColor = "e74c3c"; //alizarin red
                    break;
                case Severity.MESSAGE:
                    bgColor = "95a5a6"; //concrete grey
                    break;
                case Severity.WARNING:
                    bgColor = "9b59b6"; //amethyst purple
                    break;
            }

            return bgColor;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Would be great if any can help me out here. I really don't know how to tackle this and I am fairly new to WPF.

Net version: 4.5.1

**Edit1**
The enum is just for internal logging and looks like this:

```
enum Severity{CRITIC, WARNING, DEBUG, MESSAGE, ERROR};
```

Comment: Where do you get the severity from? That will help me answer the question. For example, if you had a function WriteLine(string str, Severity sev), you'll have to pass in Severity, but where did that Severity come from? Could you update your question with that code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. See the edit for the enum.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you, but let me know if you have any questions.

Forget about overriding the `WriteLine` function. Just encapsulate it in your own function that can handle the enum parameter & then call the base functionality just like you were doing before.

The part that I added changes the background color of the last item in the `ListView` every time it adds a new item.

New `WriteLineWithEnum` Function:

```
public void WriteLineWithEnum(string value, Severity severity)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Content = value.ToString();
        SolidColorBrush bgColorBrush = OutputBackgroundConverter.Convert(severity);
        item.Background = bgColorBrush;
        myListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Then enhance your `Convert` function to give you back a `SolidColorBrush` object that is used above to change the background color of a `ListViewItem`. Just a heads-up that I made it static and took away the 'IValueConverter' inheritance. You can add them back if you want/need.

New `Convert` function:

```
class OutputBackgroundConverter
{
    public static SolidColorBrush Convert(Severity severity)
    {
        string bgColor = "d3d3d3"; //Gray;

        switch (severity)
        {
            case Severity.CRITIC:
                bgColor = "27ae60"; //carrot orange
                break;
            case Severity.DEBUG:
                bgColor = "3498db"; //peter river blue
                break;
            case Severity.ERROR:
                bgColor = "e74c3c"; //alizarin red
                break;
            case Severity.MESSAGE:
                bgColor = "95a5a6"; //concrete grey
                break;
            case Severity.WARNING:
                bgColor = "9b59b6"; //amethyst purple
                break;
        }

        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#" + bgColor));

        return brush;
    }

}
```

I made a quick demo app that encapsulates the idea. The code and results are below.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="myListView" Margin="20">
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Random rand = new System.Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int randInt = rand.Next(100, 1000);
                string randStr = randInt.ToString();
                this.AddListViewItem(randStr, (Severity)(i % 5)); //5 is number of Severities
            }
        }

        public void AddListViewItem(string value, Severity severity)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Content = value.ToString();
            SolidColorBrush bgColorBrush = OutputBackgroundConverter.Convert(severity);
            item.Background = bgColorBrush;
            myListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public enum Severity
    {
        CRITIC = 0,
        DEBUG = 1,
        ERROR = 2,
        MESSAGE = 3,
        WARNING = 4,
    }

    class OutputBackgroundConverter
    {
        public static SolidColorBrush Convert(Severity severity)
        {
            string bgColor = "d3d3d3"; //Gray;

            switch (severity)
            {
                case Severity.CRITIC:
                    bgColor = "27ae60"; //carrot orange
                    break;
                case Severity.DEBUG:
                    bgColor = "3498db"; //peter river blue
                    break;
                case Severity.ERROR:
                    bgColor = "e74c3c"; //alizarin red
                    break;
                case Severity.MESSAGE:
                    bgColor = "95a5a6"; //concrete grey
                    break;
                case Severity.WARNING:
                    bgColor = "9b59b6"; //amethyst purple
                    break;
            }

            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#" + bgColor));

            return brush;
        }

    }
}
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Again, let me know if this doesn't do the trick & I'll try to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @james , thank you for your answer and effort. One thing you didn't consider in your answer is that the console output is redirected to a `ListView`, hence the class `ListViewWriter` that overrides `TextWriter` which is responsible for outputting the `Console.WriteLine()` to my `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll think about it some more. Do you need to be inheriting from TextWriter?